# Как писать драйвера для графики Intel?

Tags: c, freebsd, ядро

Я хочу сделать свою графический сервер и протокол для FreeBSD. Но для неё нужно писать драйвера для графики, а как писать я не знаю.
У меня три вопроса:

- Что должен реализовывать базовый графический драйвер с обыкновенной поддержной OpenGL/Vulcan?
- Как мне реализовать вызов функций из user mode в kernel mode?
- Как сделать базовый графический драйвер для Intel в виде драйвера для FreeBSD на C?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Неформат для Stack Overflow

Comment: Это на канал про анимэ)

Comment: Начните с простого - пошерстите гитхаб и схожие площадки, наверняка есть не один десяток открытых проектов по этой теме.

Comment: Профессионалы в Windows пишут так: copy con driver.sys

Comment: думаю первое, что надо сделать это заключить с Intel специальное соглашение, чтобы вам предоставили документацию

Comment: *"для неё нужно писать драйвера для графики"* - ¿А в связи с чем появилась уверенность, что это необходимо?

Comment: @user7860670,  Подведу резюм. Здешний контингент отвечающих в очередной раз продемонстрировал свой уровень

Comment: @user7860670, мне нужно получить доступ к OpenGL функциям без использования mesa, а Vesa тут не подойдёт. В исходном коде FreeBSD нет намёков на нормальный графический драйвер, а документации нет.

Comment: В вопросе вы писали "хочу сделать свою графический сервер", и с чего вдруг вам понадобилось "получить доступ к OpenGL функциям без использования mesa", и для каких нужд, - не понятно.